# Is Xdebug still recommended in Symfony dev?

Tags: symfony, debugging

The Symfony debug toolbars shows the state which tells if Xdebug is installed, looks like Symfony debug component still suggests installing Xdebug on your dev machine.

Xdebug is a debugger and profiler tools. As a debugger tool, it's nothing to do with Symfony or other frameworks, or libs.

As a profiler tool, Symfony seemed use Xdebug to gather some profile data in the old days. However, with Symfony 3, I don't see any differences between before installing Xdebug and after, from debug toolbar and the profiler page. Without Xdebug the "Performance" part of profiler page still can show the timeline of page rendering.

So I want to know what part exactly Xdebug takes in a Symfony project? should I install Xdebug as debug toolbar recommended if I don't need the remote debugging feature?

Comment: @user2182349 I know Xdebug can be a remote debugger as I mentioned in the question, but I don't think it's the reason why symfony suggest to install it. It's weird, like I suggest you use some tools like fork or chopsticks when you have your meal, most developer already know what a xdebug can do and it's not about Symfony

Answer (score 0):

No, there is absolutely no need to install Xdebug in your case!
Also, don't install in production as well.

It's only used for step-by-step debugging, and I find the `var/logs` log files much more useful.

Comment: These are two different use cases to compare usefulness. Xdebug is for iterating over one exact case, logs are best for spotting wrong patterns across many cases.